# How to make a query comparing two columns on GAE Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have an Entity Match with two columns gamesP1, gamesP2. How do I query it to return all Entities where gamesP1 > gamesP2?

Comment: Doesn't the GQL query, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE gamesP1 > gamesP2` work? Does that query work in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com)?

Comment: Nope, it says: 'GQL query error: Unknown function "gamesP2".'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore query filters [must be written](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Filters) in terms of a value provided by the application at the time of the query; they can't refer to the values of other properties.

Depending on your data model, you could define another property, `gamesDiff` that you set to `gamesP1 - gamesP2` whenever you update an entity. Then you can write the query as:

`SELECT * FROM Match WHERE gamesDiff > 0`

If you're using Python, check out [ndb's ComputedProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) which makes this easy.

Comment: How do I define that property in my datastore entity? I'm using java. You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843685/is-it-possible-to-have-a-computed-property-on-google-app-engine-using-java

Comment: If you're using Objectify, you could do something like that. If you're using the Java Datastore API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), then there's not built-in support; you'd have to update the property manually.

Comment: Well... although it looks like it's not possible to have it in the query itself (without having to have another attribute) your answer is a feasible workaround. I'm accepting it. Thanks