# App engine Datastore : How make a query / filter that return entity count with specific array size?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, datastore

I have an Entity with different properties, one of the propery is Array of Objects , I'm working with Java using Objectify

now I want to make a query with filter to return count of all entities only with specific array size , `E.g messages size=2`

Example:

```
Kind: Request
```

and 
    propery :

```
    name messeges 
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "K1": "V1",
              "K2": "V2"
            },
            {
              "K3": "V3",
              "K4": "V4"
            },
            {
              "K5": "V5",
              "K6": "V6"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Something like :

```
int count = ofy().load().type(Request.class).filter("?? return count , to query with messages size is 2..").count()
```

Any suggestions plesae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make such query with the datastore.

But you could add a property to your entity, let's call it `values_count`, to reflect the `values` array size and make an equality query on that property instead (e.g. `values_count=2`)

I'd make it a computed property, automatically updated whenever the entity is updated, see [Is it possible to have a computed property on Google App Engine using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843685/is-it-possible-to-have-a-computed-property-on-google-app-engine-using-java)

Comment: Thanks , interesting.. but if I would use  the  @OnSave method "E.g": named "computeSize" will it process and calculate the array size  , before inserting the datastore ? And do I need to call additionally this method from somewhere else ? Cause' this shows me in the IDE as "never used" method...

Comment: I'm using python/ndb and actual [computed properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed). In this context no extra calls are needed, everything happens automagically at `entity.put()` time. I suspect the same would be true for @stickfigure's solution, but I'm not 100% sure. Give it a try. The IDE *might* get confused, depending on how things are implemented under the hood. Just add a warning override comment if it's indeed the case.

Comment: Yes, Objectify will call your `@OnSave` method immediately before saving the entity to the datastore.